Choosing the right turbo for 2006 kawasaki zx14
I've been interested in and finding a turbo that fits my riding style I don't want something that's only going to be trackworthy I would still like it to keep it as a somewhat everyday Rider but still looking for something that's going to increase my speed and Power and give me that adrenaline rush that I fell in love with when first started riding. My zx 14 has been lowered stretched dyno tuned also fuel commander 5 not sure what gas map is loaded and a stage 2 clutch I've got just over 16000 miles on it so it's not clapped out still a fresh engine with lots of life left to be ridden. I ride pretty aggressive but don't flat out beat on it everytime I ride it but I do put a 1 in front of every speed limit I see. Thank you for taking the time to read this and I appreciate and am thankful for every answer and advise given. Have a great day

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
